# How to translate routes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4, routes, multilingual

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel) I'm trying to translate routes in Laravel 4.2 in english and spanish.

This is my app/routes.php code:

```
<?php


/*Set up locale and locale_prefix if other language is selected*/
if (in_array(Request::segment(1), Config::get('app.web_config.alt_langs'))) {

    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
    Config::set('app.web_config.locale_prefix', Request::segment(1));
}


foreach(Lang::get('routes') as $k => $v) {
    Route::pattern($k, $v);
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.web_config.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get('/{revelar_fotos}/',['as' => 'revelado_online', 'uses' => 'WebController@reveladoOnline'], function(){
        return 'pages.revelado_online'.App::getLocale();
    });

});
```

By clicking on the link I get this error in the url:

```
http://mywebsite.dev/%7Brevelar_fotos%7D
```

Instead of:

http://mywebsite.dev/photograph-development

This is my en/routes.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    'revelar_fotos' => 'photograph-development',
);
```

And this is my es/routes.php:

```
<?php

return array(

    'revelar_fotos' => 'revelado-online',
);
```

Why I returned this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you problem is with generating the URL `http://mywebsite.dev/%7Brevelar_fotos%7D`

In the question you only described how you did set up the routing handling and this might work. However generating the link itself is done somewhere else and in there you have not done the substitution.

You must be generating the link  something like this

```
URL::to(trans("revelar_fotos"));
```

`trans("revelar_fotos")` will get you the correct path and `URL::to()`  generates full link.

Comment: I add this to my link nav item `<li class="nav-item"><a href="{{URL::route(trans('revelar_fotos'))}}">{{trans('common.revelar_fotos')}}</a></li>` but reporter me this error -> Route [revelar_fotos] not defined

Comment: If you prefer URL::route() instead of URL::to() then you can type in `php artisan route:list` to see possible options. Also please make sure that `trans("revelar_photos")` is translated properly

Comment: I used a specify a name for my route with the 'as' array key, no sense to translate it as you say