# Multilanguage url in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to implement multilanguage urls in Laravel 5.

This example seems working in Laravel 4:
[How to create multilingual translated routes in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel)

```
foreach(Lang::get('routes') as $k => $v) {
   Route::pattern($k, $v);
}
```

I changed Lang::get() with trans(), since Lange::get() is no longer supported in L5, but I get an error:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
Any ideas how I can solve this?
Thank you

Comment: Try using https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization

Comment: First I added the "mcamara/laravel-localization": "1.1.*" in my composer.json. Then I run composer install. After that I add this line Mcamara\LaravelLocalization\LaravelLocalizationServiceProvider::class,  to the config/app.php. But then I get an error that this file can not be found. Any ideas why? Thank you

Comment: Do `composer update`

Comment: Thank you, composer update worked. After trying the example in the "Usage section" of adding the route group (['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale()]) I get a Laravel the exception : "default locale is not in the supportedLocales array" when calling url localhost/test. Any ideas why?