# Laravel 5 multi language site with language prefix in the url

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

So I need multiple languages on a site with urls like this:

```
mysite/en/language
mysite/it/language
mysite/es/language
```

I decided to go with the prefix in my routes like so:

```
$allLanguages = ["en", "it", "es"];

$lng = ( in_array( Request::segment(1), $allLanguages) ) ? Request::segment(1) : "";

Route::group(['prefix' => $lng ], function () {
    Route::get('language', function ()    {
        dd("The language is: " . Request::segment(1));
    });
});
```

It works, but if I wanted to set up a default language and access url like so *mysite/language* - it wouldn't work.

What are your thoughts? Is this the best way how to handle multi language site? How to address the problem when accessing site without prefix ( show page with default language )?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel

Answer (score 2):

After some research I found this beautiful localization class [mcamara/laravel-localization](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization/). After installation my code now looks like this and it's all working - magic!!

```
Route::group(['prefix' => LaravelLocalization::setLocale() ], function () {
    Route::get('language', function ()    {
        dd("The language is: " . LaravelLocalization::getCurrentLocale());
    });
});
```