# How to generate url to routes with two languages in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization, routes

Based on this **[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel)** I tried to implement extra english language for my website, default is french and doesn't use any prefix so something like `www.website.com` and switching to english would be `www.website.com/en/`, I'd like to have the url for contact pages such as `www.website.com/en/contact` and `www.website.com/contact` for english and french version respectively.

My current routes.php

```
if (Request::segment(1) == 'en') {
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
    Config::set('app.locale_prefix', Request::segment(1));
}
else {
    App::setLocale('fr');
    Config::set('app.locale_prefix', '');
}

Route::group(array('prefix' => Config::get('app.locale_prefix')), function()
{
    Route::get(
        '/',
        function () {
            //return "main page - ".App::getLocale();
            return view('index');
        }
    );
    Route::get(
        '/contact/',
        function () {
            return view('contact');
        });
});
```

My header file where the flag icon to switch language is

```
    @if (Lang::locale() == 'fr')
        <a href="{{ url('/en/' . Request::segment(1)) }}"><img src="{{asset('images/GB.png')}}"></a>
    @elseif (strcasecmp(Request::segment(1), 'en') == 0 && Request::segment(2) != NULL)
        <a href="{{ url( Request::segment(2)) }}"><img src="{{asset('images/FR.png')}}"></a>
    @else
        <a href="{{ url( '/') }}"><img src="{{asset('images/FR.png')}}"></a>
    @endif
```

and the way I generate urls

```
<a class="block-title" href="{{ (strcasecmp(Request::route()->getPrefix(), '/en') == 0) ? url('en/contact') : url('/contact') }}">CONTACT</a>
```

I'd like to know a cleaner way to generate these and how I can get for english main page url to be `www.website.com/en/` instead of `www.website.com/en`

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to generate URL is:

First, give a name to yor routes:

```
//this route is called 'contact_route'
Route::get('/contact/', ['as' => 'contact_route', function () 
{
    return view('contact');
}]);
```

Routes are build dynamycally using the locale and the prefix, but once a route is defined and you've give it a name, you can create a URL for the route using the [route helper](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-route) with: `route('contact_route')`

Your example will become:

```
<a class="block-title" href="{{ route('contact_route') }}">CONTACT</a>
```

You can lear more of named routes in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes)

As for the trailing slash, the default Laravel `.htaccess` file, removes all the slashes at the end of the urls, with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

That captures everything `(.*)` from the start `^` to the end before the slash `/$` and substitute it with what is captured. So, if you want to add a trailing slash, probably you should edit the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will look in further details how this route() works.

Comment: @adaba : you're welcome. I've just added a couple of links to the docs :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Route groups

All English

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en', 'namespace' => '\English'], function () {
  Route::get('contact', [
    'as'   => 'en.contact',
    'uses' => 'ContactController@contactUs',
  ]);
});
```

All French routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'fr', 'namespace' => '\French'], function () {
  Route::get('contact', [
    'as'   => 'fr.contact',
    'uses' => 'ContactController@contactUs',
  ]);
});
```