# Change Laravel language URL?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5.2 and i want to change the way how Laravel handle the languages URLs.
For example I want to call login page like this:

```
my_site.com/en/login
```

instead of calling it like this:

```
my_site.com/login
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel

Comment: Try this package https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization