# Laravel multilingual site and routes

Tags: php, laravel, routes, multilingual

I have a website in five languages and with all the URLs translated in each language for every page and I am going to update it using **Laravel 5.3**.

I have followed [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/example-on-how-to-use-multiple-locales-in-your-laravel-5-website) tutorial to add the following multilingual locales to my project:

```
'locales' => ['de' => 'German', 'en' => 'English', 'fr' => 'French', 'it' => 'Italian', 'es' => 'Spanish']
```

And this could be an example of the `Contact Us` page routes in the `web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/kontakt', 'ContactController@index');
Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@index');
Route::get('/contactez', 'ContactController@index');
Route::get('/contattaci', 'ContactController@index');
Route::get('/contacto', 'ContactController@index');
```

But if I type in the browser:
`http://localhost/myproject/en/contattaci` or `http://localhost/myproject/en/kontakt`

I can access to the Contact view, and this should not happen, just should work **contact** with the **en** locale: `/en/contact` and  **contattaci** with Italian (`/it/contattaci`) and  **kontakt** with German (`/de/kontakt`), etc.

Somebody know why is happening this or which is the right way to create the different translated routes?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel)

Comment: @Moppo I've already seen that post time ago and didn't work for me. But I  've tried to follow it again, and worked! :)
I want the `de` prefix for my default locale so I have added it also to the `alt_langs` array, but what I need now is to redirect to `/de` when is typed just the `/`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't specify the full route path. Try something like this :

```
// EN routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'en'], function() {
    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
    //... other EN routes
});
// FR routes
Route::group(['prefix' => 'fr'], function() {
    Route::get('contact', 'ContactController@index');
    //... other FR routes
});
```

But you should check @Moppo's link because there are easier ways to manage localized routes.

Comment: you can try to mask the router with and ID and relation the ID to diferent lang...

Comment: I've tried to do that, but it didn't work. I followed the tutorial that @Moppo suggested me and it worked.  But in my case, the default locale is the `/de` and I need to redirect to it when is typed just the `/`. Do you know how can I achieve that? –

Comment: `Route::get('/', function() { return redirect('/de'); });`

Comment: Where is Moppos link?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002986/laravel-multilingual-site-and-routes/40004130?noredirect=1#comment67284033_40002986)