# Routes laravel translation

Tags: laravel, translation, laravel-5.6

After much testing and searching, I can not find the solution.

My problem is that I have, for example the route '/services', '/servicios' in spanish.

If my website is in english, all texts are correctly shown in english, same in spanish. But the problem is with the text links, only appear in default locale.

In routes/web.php:

```
Route::get(trans('rutas.servicios'), 'ServiceController@index')->name('servicios')
```

File lang/es/rutas.php:

```
return [
   'servicios' => '/servicios',
];
```

File lang/en/rutas.php:

```
return [
   'servicios' => '/services',
];
```

and link html:

```
<a href="{‌{ route('servicios') }}">@lang('menus.servicios')</a>
```

My goal is to use translated urls without using laravel prefix. That is to say:

```
https://www.myweb.com/services  ~ english
https://www.myweb.com/servicios ~ spanish
```

share the same Route controller.

Any help? Lot of thanks for your time!

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION:**

I discovered that laravel performs route mapping before selecting the language. So what I did was to set the language before this, but the session and cookies variables load after this. But I finally discovered that the cached variables satisfied my needs.

At the top of function map() of RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
App::setLocale(Cache::get('locale'));
```

To store the selected locale:

```
Cache::put('locale', $locale, $minutes);
```

Comment: Are you using route cache? This could cause the url not to change.

Comment: I think I'm not using the routing cache

Comment: So problem is when you use `{‌{ route('servicios') }}` its always in Spanish?

Comment: Yes, its always in the default app locale

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel

Comment: I've seen that link before, but I do not want to use prefixes.

Comment: I found a solution! I write it at the end of my post.

Comment: Laravel already has set it's locale before running the map function in `RouteServiceProvider`. If you would `dd(App::getLocale);` in the map funcion, then you would see it will return the locale.

Comment: If you wanted to change this `AppServicerProvider@boot` would be a better place.