# How to change locale of a blade file

Tags: php, laravel

We are using IP2LOCATIONLARAVEL for getting visitors' country codes. If the visitor's IP is from Iran (ISO country code = IR), the lang attribute of the html tag in blade.php must be set as 'fa', otherwise as 'en'.

Firstly, we added this line to our config/app.php:

```
'locale' => 'en',
// we added:
'other_locale' => ['fa-IR'],
```

We also created a middleware and added it in app/Http/kernel.php properly.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Ip2location\IP2LocationLaravel\Facade\IP2LocationLaravel;

class LocaleHandler
{
    public function __construct(Application $app, Request $request) {
        $this->app = $app;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (app()->getLocale()=='fa'){
            if(in_array($request->segment(0), config('app.other_locale'))){
                $this->app->setLocale($request->segment(0));
            }else{
                $this->app->setLocale(config('app.locale'));
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Then we updated app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RouteServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
    }


    public function map(Request $request)
    {
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
        $this->mapWebRoutes($request);
    }


    protected function mapWebRoutes(Request $request)
    {
        if(in_array($request->segment(0), config('app.other_locale'))){
            $locale = $request->segment(0);

        }else{
            $locale = null;
        }

        Route::group([
            'middleware' => 'web',
            'namespace' => $this->namespace,
            'prefix' => $locale
        ], function ($router) {
            require base_path('routes/web.php');
        });

        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
    }


    protected function mapApiRoutes()
    {
        Route::prefix('api')
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
    }
}
```

localhost/laravel/public/fa is 404 error page. how can we update

```
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
```

In our blade file, if visitor country code was IR?

Comment: It's hard to say what you really want to achieve. You should set valid locale in your PHP code and in Blade you just display it as you showed.

Comment: i have 1 blade file. i want setLocale to fa if visitor is from iran. i have an if-else(for checking visitor country code) but it doesn't work: setLocale.

Comment: Take a look at answer, probably that's the problem that your middleware is never applied

Comment: '/' is en but '/fa' still error 404 and not be 'fa'

Comment: note: Route::get('/',function() { return view('welcome'); });

Comment: Have you checked the laravel log file?

Comment: The problem is that you don't have `/fa` route registered. So you should rethink your urls structure and reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

you sure added middleware in web in file kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\LocaleHandler::class,
...]
```