# How to add a default parameter for all routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-routing, laravel-localization

I have a multi lingual website. where i want to add current locale as prefix for all of my project routes. For that to be than any time i use a route i must always provide a value for locale parameter of the route. I think there are better ways of doing this.

My routes looks like this

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/blog', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('blog');
});
```

I want my path in url looks like this.

- http://localhost/project/en/blog or
- http://localhost/project/fa/blog

I also have a middleware `SetLocale` where I decide app locale according to the request path coming through;

here is my middleware code

```
class SetLocale
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {

        $locale = $request->segment(1);
        if (! is_null($locale) && ! in_array($locale, config('app.locales')) ) // config('app.locales') = ['en', 'ar', 'fa']
            abort(404);

        $html_dir = in_array($locale, ['en'])?'ltr':'rtl';
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config::set('app.html_dir', $html_dir);
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\App::setLocale($locale);


        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mohsen Amani, You may check those links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082154/how-to-create-multilingual-translated-routes-in-laravel

and  https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

  Those should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `defaults` method of the URL Generator do this exact thing:

```
URL::defaults(['locale' => $locale]);
```

Add that in your middleware and the `locale` parameter will have a default when generating a URL to routes using that parameter.

[Laravel 8.x Docs - URL Generation - Default Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/urls#default-values) `defaults`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it via Group Routes

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-groups.

Okay sorry. then what about following?

```
Route::prefix('{locale}')->middleware('SetLocale')->group(function() {
    Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::get('/blog', [App\Http\Controllers\PostController::class, 'index'])->name('blog');
});
```

Comment: I am using route groups brother, but I added a prefix for the group by the name of locale I need to give it a value. And my issue is to add value for this parameter

Comment: @MohsenAmani i updated my answer, prefix should return instance of route so you might be also be able to call middleware method as well

Comment: Sorry for my lack of explaination, you set the middleware on the route group, I also did the same but I added my middleware in the web middlewares. now I am updating question and giving more details